# data cache for odata4j

Tags: java, android, odata4j

I am implementing a RESTlet service via odata4j on Android.

When running the application there is a constant flow of data, which needs to be sent to a odata server.

The following method get's the new data:

```
private void freshData(Data data) {
    try {
        dataTransmitter.sendData(data, this.ptId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //
    }
```

The following method sends the data to the server:

```
ODataJerseyConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.create(serviceUrl);

public void sendData(Data data, int ptId) throws Exception {
    OEntity newData = c.createEntity(entitySet)
            .properties(OProperties.int32("ptID", ptID), 
             OProperties.double_("data", data.getDouble())))
            .execute;
```

So far no problem. But what if the mobile connection is cut off or lags?

**1)** Is there way to get the status from `execute()` (positive send, or no mobile connection for instance).

**2)** If the send has failed, or is still in progress I somehow need to store the new data to send it, when the old data is out. Is there a feature in odata4j (0.8-SNAPSHOT) available I haven't found, or do I need to do this with a queue for example?

Thank you for the help!